# how to use a specific branch of llvm-general with stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

In one of my projects I want to use `llvm-general` and `llvm-general-pure` but I want to use the llvm-3.9 branch which works with llvm 3.9, the latest version of these libraries on hackage are for llvm 3.5.

My project is a stack project, this is what I have in stack.yaml :

```
resolver: nightly-2017-05-01       
packages:
- '.'
- location:
     git: https://github.com/bscarlet/llvm-general.git     
     commit: 61fd03639063283e7dc617698265cc883baf0eec
  subdirs:
     - llvm-general
     - llvm-general-pure
  extra-dep: true
```

All other options are left to default.

This is my project.cabal :

```
name:                compiler-final
version:             0.1.0.0    
category:            Compiler
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lexer,Parser,ParserTestData,CodeGen
  other-modules:       Prelude,StateTUtil
  ghc-options:         -Wall -dcore-lint -fhpc -XNoImplicitPrelude -fobject-code
  build-depends:       base-noprelude >= 4.7 && < 5 , megaparsec < 6 , transformers < 1, unordered-containers < 1 , hashable < 2
                       ,classy-prelude , either < 5 , mono-traversable < 2 , logfloat < 0.14 , text
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings

executable compiler-final-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -XNoImplicitPrelude -with-rtsopts=-N -fobject-code
  build-depends:       base
                     , compiler-final
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings

test-suite compiler-final-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  other-modules:       LexerSpec , ParserSpec
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                       , compiler-final, megaparsec < 6 , hspec < 3,hspec-megaparsec >= 0.3,unordered-containers < 1
                       ,hashable,transformers < 1,text,bytestring , mtl, text
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -fhpc -Wall -XNoImplicitPrelude -fobject-code
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings
Benchmark compiler-final-bench
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      bench
  main-is:             Bench.hs
  other-modules:       ParserBench
  build-depends:       base,compiler-final,megaparsec < 6 ,unordered-containers < 1,QuickCheck<3
                       ,hashable
  ghc-options:         -rtsopts -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp -fobject-code
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Unfortunately in CodeGen.hs this simple import statement doesn't compile :  `import LLVM.General.AST`, it says it didn't find the module.

Now I have llvm-general branch 3.9 installed globally through `cabal install` and I can access it with `ghci -package`(not `stack ghci`) and the above module exists.

I tried adding `llvm-general` and `llvm-general-pure` to my dependencies list with version `3.9.0.0` but stack seems to try to install version `3.5` because it reports errors about mismatched versions.

So how to achieve what I want ?

Comment: "it reports errors about mismatched versions" Can you post the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.cabal` does not list `llvm-general` and `llvm-general-pure` as dependencies, hence why `LLVM.General.AST` is not being found.

Moreover, your `stack.yaml` is pointing to `master`, so `stack` will only see version 3.5. `stack` doesn't know anything about version 3.9 if it's not in the `stack.yaml` file. Either:

- change the commit to `ec1ad5bd2112e7f64dbb43441b5e2075cf6ad8e`;
- or, if you have the branch cloned locally, you can replace the whole `location` field corresponding to the repository with

  ```
  - location: 'path/to/llvm-general'
    extra-dep: true
  - location: 'path/to/llvm-general-pure'
    extra-dep: true
  ```